# Javascript file works with HTML on computer file but not on Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a personal website through github pages, and my last problem is that I have a javascript file that uses jQuery, that I link to in the `head` of my html file, shown below...

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

The script, CSS, HTML together work when I test the code from the files on my own computer, but when I uploaded them to github, only my HTML and CSS files work, and not my JS.

They are all located in the same branch of the repository.

Any ideas why the js file won't work?

Comment: Are you sure you have uploaded the `smoothscroll.js` and it is on the same file-level with this page?, also what are you expecting, your `head` code only adding smooth scrolling, not sure if you have other jQuery somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that your Github page is served over https. When a site is hosted using the https protocol, any resources loaded through an un-secure protocol will be blocked. This is why your jQuery will not load or run.

Try changing `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` to `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` or `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your head to the following:

```
<head>    
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

`//` should be used in lieu of `https` and or `http` when you're uncertain of which protocol that page is being accessed with (called protocol agnostic) and you're including a resource from another domain that supports both protocols.  `Domains domains ports and protocols must match`

Comment: why not always use https?

Comment: You certainly could but I prefer to match schemes.  Http is marginally faster and if there's any hangup with SSL the resource isn't going to be loaded.